# How to test my iphone app using the SDK 3.2?

Tags: iphone, testing, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have downloaded the latest iphone sdk 3.2 beta and my problem is I cannot test my apps on the device because the device (iphone or ipod touch) runs the firmware 3.1.2

any solutions?

if their is no answer just tell me how to develop iphone apps compatible with 3.1.2 using the SDK 3.2

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to test apps built with 3.2 on your devices until a firmware is released.
Until then you have to use the simulator or build your apps with 3.1.2 SDK.
You can have several SDK version installed and choose which one to build for.

EDIT: AFAIK, there isn't anything new or changed regarding to the "iphone" in SDK 3.2 so there isn't really any point using it unless you want to develop for the iPad.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the SDK version from xCode menu Project->Edit-Project-setting and then change the SDK version from the the tab "Build" Thanks Martinj

Comment: And as iPhone SDK 3.2 Beta is under NDA, its better to raise related questions at the Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: You are incorrect there is nothing new for the iPhone, many of the new features work on the iPhone (in the simulator) in addition to the iPad (I cannot give specifics of course).  You just have to test them in the simulator until we get a device build.

Answer (score 0):

Set the project base target (`Project->Edit Project Settings->General`) as 3.1 and study up on the same weak framework references they had us use from 2.2.1 to 3.0 - you'll not be able to test 3.2 specific features on the device but at least you'll be able to test some things, if you code carefully you can make most of the new features conditional which might be a good idea anyway since you probably want to support OS 3.1 for at least a little while.